# How to remove <p><br></p> tags in summernote value?

Tags: html, angularjs, summernote

While entering space in staring am getting following code from summernote textarea,

```
<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><strong style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

but i want to remove the starting **`<p><br></p><p><br></p>`** before storing to db.

for example i want to store like below,

```
<p><strong style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span><br></p>
```

Comment: Use `angular.element` to create a `<div>` to put that html string in then loop over `<p>` elements and remove if no text. Then use `html()` to get result to send to db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure about the pattren than You can achieve it something like

```js
var data='<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><strong style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>';
while(data.startsWith('<p><br></p>')){
data=data.replace('<p><br></p>','')
}

while(data.endsWith('<p><br></p>')){
data=data.replace(new RegExp('<p><br></p>$'),'')
}
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Than you @jitender, for short time i can use, but i want <p><br></p> in between text, only starting and ending text should be replace. for your solution it will replace full text where ever  <p><br></p> is available.

Comment: if you are sure that you have to replace  `<p><br></p>` in start  and end than check out updated answer

Answer (score 3):

```
callbacks: {
  onFocus: function (contents) {
    if($('.summernote').summernote('isEmpty')){
      $(".summernote").html(''); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do this:

```
$('.summernote_add').summernote({
    height: 250,
    callbacks: {
        onChange: function (contents) {
            if ($('.summernote_add').summernote('isEmpty')) {
                $(".add .panel-body").html('');
            } else {
                $(".add .panel-body").val(contents);
            }
            // $('.summernote_add').val(
            //     $('.summernote_add').summernote('isEmpty')
            //         ? null
            //         : contents
            // );
            summernoteValidatorAdd.element($('.summernote_add'));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote('code', '<text H>');
```

Instead of:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertText', '<text H>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 250,
    callbacks: {
        onInit: function (c) {
            c.editable.html('');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the empty element

```
$("p").each(function(){
    if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ox32tjwg/

Comment: Question is tagged angular...not jQuery

Comment: please use angular js

Comment: Hi Ismail, This solution has a problem, Use just one emoji in the summernote Textarea and so test this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This **worked** for me! had to do it just now

```
callbacks: {
  onFocus: function (contents) {
    if($(this).summernote('isEmpty')){
      $("<your-selector>").html(''); //either the class (.) or id (#) of your textarea or summernote element
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this callback. You will be left with one pair of `<p><be></p>` which is fine as per the documentation. OnBlur, you are just resetting the Summernote so that it will remove all other leftover tags.

See the documentation here:

*isEmpty
Returns whether editor content is empty or not.
The editing area needs `<p><br></p>` for focus, even if the editor content is empty. So Summernote supports this method for helping to check if editor content is empty.*

```
onBlur: function (contents) {
  if (
    $($('#body-summernote').summernote('code')).text().trim().length < 1
  ) {
    console.log(
      $($('#body-summernote').summernote('code')).text().trim().length
    );
    console.log('clearing');
    // $('#body-summernote').html('');
    $('#body-summernote').summernote('reset');
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove just leading/start tags then use it with regular expression otherwise it also removes other tags that are not leading/start tags and you can also remove ending/trainling tags by using single loop.

```
let value='<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><strong style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>';


while(value.startsWith('<p><br></p>') || value.endsWith('<p><br></p>')){
     
    value=value.replace(new RegExp('^<p><br></p>'),'').trim();
      
    value=value.replace(new RegExp('<p><br></p>$'),'').trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this callback which even works if you have several summernotes on your page:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  height: 150,
  toolbar: [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['insert', ['link']]
  ],
  callbacks: {
    onChange: function(contents) {
      if (contents == '<p><br></p>') {              
        var currentSummernoteInstance = $(this);
        currentSummernoteInstance.summernote('code', '');
      }
    }
  }
})
```